# Is it natural to say "Look up from under the table. Can you see the note?" in everyday conversations?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

There is a table and a note.

The note is stuck on the bottom surface of the table as shown in the above picture.

**Is it natural to say in everyday conversations?**

**-Look under the table. Can you see the note?**

**-Look up from under the table. Can you see the note?**

**-Look at the bottom surface of the table. Can you see the note?**

Comment: It's hardly a common thing for anyone to need to say in 'everyday conversations'! "Look up from under the table" suggests that the person is already crawling under the table. I suppose you might start by saying "Look under the table", and if they still didn't find it, go into more detail about the note's exact position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal conversation it might be:

> Look up under the table. Can you see the note?

This gives a context to find the note. Just saying:

> Look under the table.

Leaves the person looking at the floor and table legs.
The use of **from** in your original phrase is not necessary.

Comment: But some native speakers say it is not as correct as "look at the note on the underside of the table"